# Elements of positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, schur-complement

Consider the symmetric matrix

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
b^T & c
\end{bmatrix}\succ 0
\end{equation}

By assumption $c\succ 0$. I want to prove that $a\succ 0$.  For the Schur complement (or other lemma) is it possible to prove it?

Comment: It is possible to do so, but why do you want to do it? Isn't it much easier to prove that $a>0$ by considering $(1,0)\pmatrix{a&b\\ b&c}\pmatrix{1\\ 0}$?

Comment: A principal submatrix of a PSD matrix is PSD.

Comment: I was trying to explain it with Schur. Knowing that the entire matrix $M> 0$ then $a- bc^{-1}b^T > 0 \rightarrow a >bc^{-1}b^T$ so can I conclude that $a>0$?

Comment: Yes, that's a valid conclusion, but it doesn't really enhance your understanding. You see, your whole argument shows that if one diagonal element of $M$ is positive, the other one must be positive too, but it doesn't explain why some diagonal element has to be positive in the first place.

Comment: For my case study, this is a covariance matrix and $c = E[u(t)u(t)]$. If $u$ is persistently exciting of some order, the matrix is PD and in particular $c>0$. I wanted to understand if we can also conclude that $a = E[x(t)x(t)]>0$ .